# gethostbyname and endianness - how are the bytes returned?

Tags: winapi, language-agnostic, winsock, endianness

On my (Intel) x86 machine, I've noticed that if I `printf` the results of `gethostbyname` for `localhost`, I get `100007F`, even though the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states it should return the IP in network byte order, aka big endian. I searched a bit and found [this topic](http://www.justskins.com/forums/gethostbyname-confusion-104235.html). Based on the answers there, I've deduced the sequence of bytes will be the same no matter the endianness, so, for `localhost`, I'd have this in memory on both Intel and AMD chips:

`7F|00|00|01`

Thus, *reading* that memory with an Intel chip results in a 'reversed' result, while on an AMD CPU, I'd get 0x7F000001. Is that assumption correct? It seems like the only possible explanation, but I want to make sure.

This is the code I'm using:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    //-----------------------------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    DWORD dwError;
    int i = 0;

    struct hostent *remoteHost;
    char *host_name;
    struct in_addr addr;

    char **pAlias;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    host_name = "localhost";


    // If the user input is an alpha name for the host, use gethostbyname()
    // If not, get host by addr (assume IPv4)
    if (isalpha(host_name[0])) {        /* host address is a name */
        printf("Calling gethostbyname with %s\n", host_name);
        remoteHost = gethostbyname(host_name);
    }
    else {
        printf("Calling gethostbyaddr with %s\n", host_name);
        addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_name);
        if (addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE) {
            printf("The IPv4 address entered must be a legal address\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
            remoteHost = gethostbyaddr((char *)&addr, 4, AF_INET);
    }

    if (remoteHost == NULL) {
        dwError = WSAGetLastError();
        if (dwError != 0) {
            if (dwError == WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND) {
                printf("Host not found\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else if (dwError == WSANO_DATA) {
                printf("No data record found\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("Function failed with error: %ld\n", dwError);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Function returned:\n");
        printf("\tOfficial name: %s\n", remoteHost->h_name);
        for (pAlias = remoteHost->h_aliases; *pAlias != 0; pAlias++) {
            printf("\tAlternate name #%d: %s\n", ++i, *pAlias);
        }
        printf("\tAddress type: ");
        switch (remoteHost->h_addrtype) {
        case AF_INET:
            printf("AF_INET\n");
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            printf("AF_INET6\n");
            break;
        case AF_NETBIOS:
            printf("AF_NETBIOS\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf(" %d\n", remoteHost->h_addrtype);
            break;
        }
        printf("\tAddress length: %d\n", remoteHost->h_length);

        if (remoteHost->h_addrtype == AF_INET) {
            while (remoteHost->h_addr_list[i] != 0) {
                addr.s_addr = *(u_long *)remoteHost->h_addr_list[i++];
                printf("\tIPv4 Address #%d: %X %s\n", i, addr.s_addr, inet_ntoa(addr));
            }
        }
        else if (remoteHost->h_addrtype == AF_INET6)
            printf("\tRemotehost is an IPv6 address\n");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

[image]

NOTE: I've had a friend run this on his AMD CPU, and surprisingly, apparently it's `100007F` for him as well. Is my previous assumption wrong, or is my friend drunk?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you use one of the `ntohx` functions to convert the network byte order to the host byte order, for example [`ntohs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @honk Of course I could, but I'm trying to understand why the returned value (seemingly) is in the wrong endianness.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't really get where you were aiming at. Can you add the code to your question that shows how you accessed and printed the variable you are talking about?

Comment: @honk Oops, of course, I've forgotten to add it to the question. Updated now.

Comment: Can you add all your code starting from `gethostbyname` up to the `printf`? Can you also add the exact output of your program and how you think it should be?

Comment: @honk Done, see question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addresses contained in the `hostent` structure are in network byte order.

If you have code that suggests otherwise then you are misinterpreting that code and reaching the wrong conclusion.

In network byte order, on a little endian host, `127.0.0.1` is `0x0100007f`. To see how this works, remember that on a little endian host, the least significant byte is stored first. That's `0x7f`. So the bytes appear in this order in memory, `0x7f`, `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x01`. And that therefore represents `127.0.0.1`.

Now, those same bytes on a big endian host would represent a different 32 bit value. On a big endian host, the first byte if the most significant, and so `0x7f`, `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x01` would represent the value `0x7f000001`.

Comment: Yes, this much is clear to me; since I'm using MSDN code, I think there's no problems there, so I'm trying to find out where I'm making that mistake.

Comment: Yes, the explanation is nice, thank you :). I've added that comment before you edited the answer. One more question: as stated in the original post, my friend ran this on an AMD chip which is big-endian, but got the same result. Why? Shouldn't it be `0x7F000001` as you said?

Comment: I don't believe that this AMD chip really is big endian. Windows only runs on little endian machines. The AMD chip your friend has is another little endian x86 machine.

Comment: Indeed, I just checked and you're right. Well, my assumptions were quite wrong then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

AMD chips are little endian, like Intel chips.  There's no difference.

If you want to see the big-endian result, you need to run on a big-endian system, such as as ARM or MIPS chip running in big-endian mode, or a SPARC, or PPC, or 68K or ALPHA, or any of the many older big-endian architectures that are now rare (ARM and MIPS are mixed-endian chips that can be configured to run in either big-endian or little-endian mode, though they generally run in big-endian mode).

Comment: I don't know, I was convinced AMDs are primarily big-endian, not sure why. Anyway since Windows cannot run on big-endian (apart from some obscure versions), this ceases to be a problem.